# How to hide sidebar widgets in all pages except Hompage?

Tags: widgets, sidebar

im using a sidebar widget in homepage for an extra gallery. sadly it appears in every pages ._. thanks in advance

Comment: Please take a look at the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) to figure out where you want that sidebar to appear and where not. Then read  [ask] to see how you can make your question answerable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, quick option: use a plugin called "[dynamic widgets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-widgets/)"; it provides an interface the where you can specify the conditions under which each of your widgets should appear.

Slightly more involved option is to edit your theme, so that it has two sidebars, both registered as widget areas, and include one of them only on the `front-page.php` (if you have a static front page), or `home.php` (if you have a blogfeed front page).

Comment: looks cool! let me see

Comment: Worked Awsome. ty

Comment: sure dude it was on cooldown! :D

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.

Answer (score 2):

writing a minimal plugin (´functions.php´) like this should do:

```
add_action('wp_head', function(){       
    if ( is_home() ) return; // on home it's okay

    unregister_sidebar('sidebar-1');
    echo '<style>
        .content-area {
            margin-right: inherit;
            width: 100%;
        }
        </style>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

writing a minimal plugin (´functions.php´) like this should do:

```
add_action('wp_head', function(){       
    if ( is_home() ) return; // on home it's okay

    unregister_sidebar('sidebar-1');
    echo '<style>
        .content-area {
            margin-right: inherit;
            width: 100%;
        }
        </style>';
});
```

Of course, `'sidebar-1'` and the *counter-styling* is template-specific (twenty sixteen in this case), needs adjustment to the theme you use.